# Wrap every character of a timestamp in `<span>` element

Tags: javascript, html

I am using Moment.js to display city times. For example, the time in Chicago:

```js
const chicago = moment().tz("America/Chicago").format("hh:mm");
```

The output will be: `"00:00"`.

I would like the output to be like that:

```html
<span>0</span>
<span>0</span>
<span class="no-bg">:</span>
<span>0</span>
<span>0</span>
```

Any help how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrapping every character in a `<span>` can be achieved with [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) and [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```js
const chicago = moment().tz("America/Chicago").format("hh:mm");

const result = Array.from(chicago, (character) => {
    const span = Object.assign(document.createElement("span"), {
      textContent: character
    });

    if(character === ":"){
      span.classList.add("no-bg")
    }
    
    return span;
  });
```

`result` will be an array of `<span>` elements.

If you expect linebreaks between these `<span>`s, create the array with [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) instead:

```js
const chicago = moment().tz("America/Chicago").format("hh:mm");

const result = Array.from(chicago)
    .flatMap((character) => {
      const span = Object.assign(document.createElement("span"), {
        textContent: character
      });

      if(character === ":"){
        span.classList.add("no-bg")
      }
      
      return [
        span,
        document.createTextNode("\n")
      ];
    })
    .slice(0, -1);
```

[Append](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append) them to some `container` element:

```js
container.append(...result);
```

Or concatenate them as a string:

```js
result.map(({outerHTML, textContent}) => outerHTML ?? textContent).join("");
```

[`outerHTML ?? textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) is used to ensure that HTML elements are stringified to their [HTML format](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML), but [text nodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text) get stringified to their [text content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent).

If you have more than one clock, iterate them in an array:

```js
const clocks = [
    "America/Chicago",
    "UTC",
    "Europe/Berlin",
    "America/Vancouver",
    "Africa/Maseru",
    "Pacific/Port_Moresby"
  ];

container.append(...clocks.map((timeZone) => {
  const div = document.createElement("div");
  
  div.append(...Array.from(moment().tz(timeZone).format("hh:mm"), (character) => {
    const span = Object.assign(document.createElement("span"), {
      textContent: character
    });

    if(character === ":"){
      span.classList.add("no-bg")
    }

    return span;
  }));
  
  return div;
}));
```

Comment: Great answer @Sebastian Simon
I need the first solution without linebreaks.  How do I output it as HTML?

Comment: @gilhamer There are two options at the end of the answer already: use either the one with `.append` or the one with `outerHTML`.

Comment: Great thanks! it works great. one more thing if possible:  Id like to have multiple cities (clocks) wrapped with DIV. what's the best way of having variable and use the same code replacing the "city" with variable based on the city?

Comment: @gilhamer Designate a `container` for all clocks and map each timezone to a `<div>` to append them all; see the edited answer. For more, familiarize yourself with the [DOM API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model).

Comment: One more question @Sebastian if I may.. anyway I can simply and easily make the clocks run dynamical and change time every minute? thanks